# show filter values even if the data is not available in table

Tags: postgresql, cockroachdb

So there is the Table and their contents As shown below.

| id | title | image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First | row |
| 2 | Second | row |
| 3 | third | row |

So if we see in the table there are only 3 records and the id are 1,2,3
There is no entry for 4,5 in the table so no data.
Query:--

```
select "id", "title", "image" 
FROM "table" 
WHERE "id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

So there are only 3 records in the table but in the where clause there are 5 id. So expecting output to be as shown below:--

| id | title | image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First | row |
| 2 | Second | row |
| 3 | Third | row |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |

So even if there is no data in table the id need to be shown empty if it is present in the IN operator select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the IN operator, but you could OUTER JOIN to a VALUES clause or unnest an array:

```
SELECT id, title, image
FROM table
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT unnest(ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) as u(id)
USING (id);
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iVimf41JVfL5Y8sAxdjpza/0).

Comment: Instead of unnest(ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) can we add something like this unnest(ARRAY[arr]))?
arr is an array which has all the elements.
So the arr is dynamic which has to be passed to the above query. 
I'm getting error wen i pass the dynamic value.

Comment: @user9243500  You need to omit `ARRAY` if it is already an array, just using `unnest($1)`